# Add a Custom Header on a TISAPIRequest (Delphi 10.1 Datasnap Server)

Tags: http, delphi, datasnap

Do you know how to manually add a custom header on a TISAPIRequest ?.

This class (or the most generic TWebRequest) doesn't expose a RawHeaders property to allow adding new customized Headers when needed.

PS: I have a dirty solution for when my WebRequest is a TIdHTTPAppRequest (Datasnap standalone server), because then I can create a Helper Class to access to its private FRequestInfo property, and from there gain access to a RawHeaders, which I can use to add a new header. But I only use standalone servers for development and testing, the production environment must run on IIS servers.

```
TIdHTTPAppRequestHelper = class helper for TIdHTTPAppRequest
  public
    function GetRequestInfo: TIdEntityHeaderInfo;
  end;

implementation

function TIdHTTPAppRequestHelper.GetRequestInfo: TIdEntityHeaderInfo;
begin
  Result := FRequestInfo;
end;

procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var Token: string;
begin
  Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

  Token := Request.Query;

  if Copy(Token, 1, 10) = 'dssession=' then begin
    if Request is TIdHTTPAppRequest then begin
      TIdHTTPAppRequest(Request).GetRequestInfo.RawHeaders.AddValue('Pragma', Token);
    end;
  end;

  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
    FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

It is possible to write a similar code to get the same result (to add a custom header to your WebRequest) when the WebRequest is a TISAPIRequest instead of THTTPAppRequest ?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TISAPIRequest`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Web.Win.IsapiHTTP.TISAPIRequest) has a public [`ECB`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Web.Win.IsapiHTTP.TISAPIRequest.ECB) property, which returns a pointer to the ISAPI [`EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525658.aspx) structure that represents the underlying request data.  However, the `ECB` does not allow you to alter the request headers in any way, only read values from them.  You can set custom response headers via the `ECB`, though.

The only way I can find to add/modify custom request header values in ISAPI is to write an [ISAPI Filter DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610.aspx), which is outside the scope of `TISAPIRequest` handling.  Inside the DLL's exported [`HttpFilterProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525878.aspx) function, the `SF_NOTIFY_PREPROC_HEADERS` notification provides an [`HTTP_FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525034.aspx) structure that contains pointers to [`AddHeader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525434.aspx) and [`SetHeader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525099.aspx) functions for adding/modifying request header values.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I'm gonna look to write that ISAPI Filter.