# DataSnap Server - Send custom HTTP response headers

Tags: rest, delphi, httpresponse, datasnap

I have built a standalone (Delphi EXE) DataSnap server using `TDSServer`, `TDSServerClass` etc.  I want to be able to send custom HTTP headers in the response from my server methods.  I can see I can use `GetInvocationMetadata()` to customise the response status code, message, content and the `Content-Type` header, but can't see any way of adding my own response headers.  Is this possible?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901343/add-a-custom-header-on-a-tisapirequest-delphi-10-1-datasnap-server

Comment: Unfortunately not, that looks like the WebBroker framework which is not what I'm using - I don't have a TWebModule or TWebResponse.

Comment: If you use the Server Wizard to build a Datasnap server (REST), you'd have more opportunity to investigate the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
function TControllerAplicacao.EchoString(Value: string): string;
var
 objWebModule: TWebModule; //need Web.HTTPApp
begin
  //the Solution
  objWebModule := GetDataSnapWebModule; //need Datasnap.DSHTTPWebBroker
  objWebModule.Response.SetCustomHeader('MY-CUSTOM-HEADER','ABCD12324');
  //do the test using postman, and see on HEADERS

 Result := Value; //from original datasnap example EchoString

end;
```